# JDK 1.6 for OSX

Tags: macos, java, jdk

I am trying to use the Java game library Slick2d. However it seems like it's bugged using Java 1.7. I've tried to find it but was unsuccessful.

Is it possible to install the 1.6 JDK on Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 0):

I run with java 6 on mountain lion.
You should [remove java7](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) before installing java 6